# How to assign string outputs of expressions in variables without echo?

Tags: bash

I am currently saving string outputs from expressions like so

```
SOME_PATH="/some/path/file"
FILE_NAME=`echo "$SOME_PATH" | rev | cut -f 1 -d "/" | rev )`
FILE_FOLDER=`echo "$SOME_PATH" | sed s/$FILE_NAME//`

echo ${SOME_PATH}
echo ${FILE_NAME}
echo ${FILE_FOLDER}
```

which seems like the echo is superfluous, but I couldn't get it to work without it. What is the preferred way?

Comment: I suggest a [here string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings).

Comment: So you want the `basename` and the `dirname`? These commands do exactly this: `basename /some/path/file --> file`, and `dirname /some/path/file --> /some/path`.

Comment: you could use basename and dirname to simplify this also $( xxyyy ) should be used in preference to backticks (which is inherited from sh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the preferred way?

The preferred way is to use variable expansions.

```
somepath='/some/path'
filename=${somepath##*/}
dirname=${somepath%/*}
```

Also: do not use backticks `, prefer `$(...)`, quote variable expansions `"s/$FILE_NAME//"`, prefer to use lower case variables for local variables and check your scripts with shellcheck.

> How to assign string outputs of expressions in variables without echo?

Use here string to save one `fork()` call.

```
var=$(<<<"$var" command)
```

Comment: ``FILE_NAME=$(<<<"$SOME_PATH" | rev | cut -f 1 -d "/" | rev )`` doesn't work

Comment: It works for the basename and dirname commands from Renaud Pacalet though. Can you explain why the variable expansions are better?

Comment: `<<<"$SOME_PATH" | rev` not `<<<"$var" | command` but `<<<"$var" command`. `<<<"$var"` is not a command, it does nothing, `|` pipeing it does nothing. `why the variable expansions are better?` Because they do not spawn external processes.